# This use statement conflicts with another class in this namespace

Tags: php, laravel

I developed a Laravel plugin, and, in all my factory classes, I get a warning from Scrutinizer that tells me:

> ```
> use Xoco70\KendoTournaments\Models\Category;
> ```
>
> This use statement conflicts with another class in this namespace, Category, in
>
> ```
> $factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) { 
>
> ... }
> ```

Thing is I have it defined it `package/xoco70/my-plugin/src` and in `/vendor/xoco70/my-plugin/src/`

Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `as`:

```
use Xoco70\KendoTournaments\Models\Category as XocoCategory;
```

And the use this alias:

```
$factory->define(XocoCategory::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    ...
}
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: it worked. but it is not so great, Category reflects better my concept that XocoCategory :( any luck doing something else? As it worked, I put it as answer!

Comment: Alias can be any, no required ```XocoCategory```. Classes with the same namespace should be with different names.